# vue change data cause memory leak?

Tags: vue.js

```
<script>
import { callApi } from "./api";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function() {
    return {
      geoJson: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      callApi().then(res => {
        this.geoJson = res.data;
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="fetchData">Fetch data</button>
</template>
```

each time I click a button trigger fetching data, the heap memory goes up.

I've checked there is no other variable refer to this.geoJson

not sure what cause this

thanks.

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-chaplygin-7sj56

[image]

Comment: is this in development or in production? do you have devtools enabled?

Comment: I found this problem both in production and development mode

Comment: because the way vue works(getters/setters and in vue 3 proxies) .when ever you store a big js obj in reactive var. its gonna consume more size than original js object. the wrost part came when you use computed and vuex getters which will cache it too. there is tricky way to overcome this problem. you will store the big js obj in non reactive var and also you will have some reactive id var which will change every time the non reactive var changed. in this way you can notify and react to changes in the big js obj. i can send example in answer if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heap size grows because you are allocating new objects that live on the heap. Like you mention, there are no extra references to that value so when it is overwritten, the old value becomes **garbage** (not freed). It *still exists on the heap* despite not being reachable from anywhere until the garbage collector reclaims it.

Try clicking on the `Collect Garbage` (garbage can icon near the record button) to manually trigger it and see the heap size drop again.

Comment: thanks , but what if user click the button multiple time on a SPA and doesn't manually trigger garbage collection, will the page go crash eventually?  as far as i know, it should be garbage collected automatically, but it never go down until I reload the page...

Comment: It's not your job to manage the garbage collector. When the heap is getting too large, yes, the garbage collector will kick in.

Comment: after I click fetch data many many times, the browser show "paused before potential out-of-memory crash"

Comment: Are you using the version from your question or the one from the sandbox? Your sandbox version also logs the object which could prevent it from being collected but I wrote this w.r.t the code you put in the question.

Comment: @justin87qq did it lower the heap size once you click the Collect Garbage button?